# Why laravel logging entire env file?

Tags: php, laravel, environment-variables

I've notice that Laravel (5.1) is logging the entire .env file when I try to log something else not related.

Here's an example:

```
[2016-05-05 14:26:58] APP_ENV=local
APP_DEBUG=true
APP_URL=dev.mywebsite
APP_KEY=123321123123123123123123

DB_HOST=localhost
DB_DATABASE=mywebsite
DB_USERNAME=root
DB_PASSWORD=....DEBUG: teste at  on line . Data: []
```

Which should be:

```
[2016-05-05 14:26:58] DEBUG: teste at  on line . Data: []
```

I guess that this started when I change the env file to run according my host. This is what I changed:

```
- ./bootstrap
--- environment.php
- ./env
--- ./env/.development.env
--- ./env/.production.env
```

... this is what I have at **environment.php**

```
$env = $app->detectEnvironment(function() {

  $dir = __DIR__.'/../env/';

  if(!isset($_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'])) {
    return getenv('APP_ENV');
  }

  switch($_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']) {
    case 'mywebsite.herokuapp.com':
    $dotenv = '.production.env';
    $getenv = 'production';
    break;

    default:
    $dotenv = '.development.env';
    $getenv = getenv('APP_ENV');
    break;
  }

  $content = trim(file_get_contents($dir . $dotenv));

  putenv('APP_ENV='.$content);
  Dotenv::load($dir, $dotenv);

  return $getenv;

});
```

The env files it's working, but I don't get it why the content of the file is been printed at log file.

Comment: You should put this as an answer and mark the question as answered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nerver mind, the problem was that if I'm using **Dotenv**, I dont need to use **putenv**.

So the code will be:

```
$env = $app->detectEnvironment(function() {

  $dir = __DIR__.'/../env/';
  $host = (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']) ? $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] : 'local');

  switch($host) {
    case 'mywebsite.herokuapp.com':
    $dotenv = '.production.env';
    break;

    default:
    $dotenv = '.local.env';
    break;
  }

  Dotenv::load($dir, $dotenv);

  return getenv('APP_ENV');

});
```